# What are names and dates in this Status Animarum for Mali Cirnik 13?

Tags: palaeography, austria-hungary, kurrent, vital-records, german-language

Here is a German [Status Animarum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parish_family_book) for the Mali Cirnik 13 (Kleinz Zirnik) household in the Šentrupert parish in the early 1800s.  I've added what I think are the names and dates as written in German, but expect I have errors as I'm slowly learning to read the [Kurrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurrent) handwriting used here.  Note there are no column headers.

[image]

Please help with any corrections and filling in sections I couldn't figure out, including what is crossed out.  Also, what is the translation to English for the notes.  I think the last column is discussing a marriage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of your transcript matches my reading. Corrections/alternate transcriptions:

```
        ...Weib, Maria Sladizh ...
        ...Tochter, Maria  ...geheirathet nach Posharzhe Rikarerd? Johanistha[l?, 
lost in margin] [=married (in)to Posharzhe...]
        ...
        ...Anna Greleng? [pencilled in, no date]
```

Notes:
Location of Posharzhe tbd - best matches by name (using [GOV](http://gov.genealogy.net/search/index)) are in Serbia [Pozarevaz] or in the Ukraine [Pozharkivska], but those may be unlikely given the distances from Mali Cirnik. Format of the 3 words usually means village, jurisdiction word, county or larger entity, but the middle word may be an intermediate jurisdiction or an indicator that the final word is an alternate name for Posharzhe (Johannisthal (and variant spellings) is the name of several villages and towns all over eastern Europe).

The 1847s referenced on Ursula's and Marianna's lines may be death years (Marianna would be too young for marriage).

Comment: I agree with most of bgwiehle's corrections. According to Wikipedia Mali Cirnik in Šentrupert parish is also called Mali Cirnik pri Šentjanžu. and Šentjanž was previously referred to as Johannisthal. This makes the geography consistent. I do not think that the final reading of the linking word between "Posharzhe" and "Johannisthal" has been found yet, though.

Comment: @user3697176 I think that Maria married a Jožef Zaman on 13 Feb 1854 and that Jožef was from Gorn Lakin, where "Gorn" means "Upper". Perhaps that helps with the linking word?

Comment: It appears the wife of Maria is [Jožef Šuštaršič](https://www.ancestry.com/family-tree/person/tree/119400886/person/360184041984/facts) who was born in Posharche 19, Šentjanž.