# What is the meaning of the cross symbol I see added to individuals in Status Animarium records?

Tags: 19th-century, vital-records, catholic-church, austria-hungary

I've seen this cross image (underlined in red) occur repeatedly in the Catholic church Status Animarium records starting from the mid-1800s, such as the following example:
[image]
Is there any significance to whether the cross is simple or has serifs at end of the cross hairs, or is that just up to the writer's style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, a cross preceeding or following a name indicates "deceased". If there is a date, it is "died on" (that date). Both styles were used over centuries of records, although my subjective impression is that the fancier form is older.

The cross was also used in the image for [What are names and dates in this Status Animarum for Mali Cirnik 13?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/what-are-names-and-dates-in-this-status-animarum-for-mali-cirnik-13), and included in your transcription. Sorry: I didn't pick up on expanding that symbolic use in my answer.

Comment: Ah, so the 'plus' sign there is really a cross?

Comment: Might be of interest: http://wiki-de.genealogy.net/Genealogische_Symbole_und_Zeichen (Many of the symbols are more likely to be used in published family trees, but the some of them are also used in church records).